# Setting the default value of state variable as output of a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-deployment

I have a state variable:

```
const [rowValues, setRowValues] = React.useState(() => {
            setAllValues(false);
        });
```

I have attempted to initialize the default value in the [Lazy Initialization Fashion](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state)
In other words, i want the default value of the state to be the return value of `setAllValues(false)`.

Now here is the `setAllValues` function:

```
async function setAllValues(value) {
        await rows.forEach((element) => {
            temp = { ...temp, [element.id]: value };
        });
        console.log('| temp', temp);
        return temp;
    }
```

`rows` is a variable destructured from the props. Initial renders, the value is `[]`, next times it renders as the expected value. Look at the image to better under-stand what im saying here:
[image]

Since the initial value of `rows` is `[]`, the state gets the wrong default value. I want the function (`setAllValues(false)`) to run when the value of `rows` is `[{...},{...},{...}..]` , or how do i prevent rows from having the value `[]`? Please Help.

Comment: why is setAllValues async? `Array.prototype.forEach()` is sync code.

Comment: @PabloRecalde I have removed the async await, what next?

Comment: `React.useState(setAllValues(false));`

Comment: i believe you want to use map to return the new array. rowValues should be an array?

Comment: @PabloRecalde Like i said, it is considering the value of rows when it initially is `[]` i dont want that to happen, i want it to consider the value only when its defined. Look at the image in the post for more clarity

Comment: @urchmaney no `rowValues` is an object

Comment: so what modifies the value of `rows`? I guess you can `useEffect` and set the correct value into the state when `rows` changes?

Comment: @PabloRecalde rows is being passed as a prop. I tried to use useEffect, but that changes the state, and not the default value of the state. I need to change the default value of the state as I am getting a " A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value " Error.

Comment: What exactly do you want the initial state to be when rows is `[]`?  And can't you control how row is been passed down from it parent? Cause since the props is coming from the parent and it initially sends `[]` before then sending array with values, then that should the point of focus. possble add the code that pass props to this component.

Comment: @urchmaney all i want to do is set the state's default value as the value of rows when its `[{...},{...},{...}]` , what do you suggest?